# Select count with LIKE operator in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have defined these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE domain (
  id          BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
  name       varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE url (
  id         BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
  url       text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

And I want to count how many urls for each domain. I try to do this like this:

```
SELECT
    domain.name AS dn,
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM url WHERE url.url ILIKE '%' || dn || '%'
```

but without luck. Got Syntax error.
How to make it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select d.name, count(*)
from
    domain d
    inner join
    url u on split_part(u.url, '/', 3) like '%' || d.name
group by 1
```

Extracting the domain from the url will avoid matches where the domain appears in the path or query string parts.

Comment: I've just done some experimentation with split_part and I think you want ,3 rather than ,1. For `http://example.com` `split(url, '/', 1)` returns `http:`. `split(url, '/', 3)` returns `example.com`. Overall I think your answer is better than mine if the data always contains a fully formed schema, whereas my answer is better if the data could be a mixture of `http://example.com` and `example.com`.

Comment: @AndyNichols you are right. With 1 this query doesn't return anything but when I change it to 3 this runs fine

Comment: @AndyNichols Yes, I did not think of the protocol. If the protocol is missing in some of the urls then the best option would be the `regexp_split_to_array` function

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do a join between the tables and then group by the domain name. This leads to

```
SELECT d.name as dn, COUNT(*) as number_of_urls
FROM domain d
INNER JOIN url u ON u.url ILIKE '%'||d.name||'%'
GROUP BY d.name
```

This will NOT give a row for any domains with zero entries in the url table. If you need these rows change the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`